# There exists $0 \neq a \in R$ such that $a^n = 0$, then there exists $0 \neq b \in R$ such that $b^2 = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring and $n > 2$ a positive integer. Show that if there exists $0 \neq a \in R$
> such that $a^n = 0$, then there exists $0 \neq b \in R$ such that $b^2 = 0$.

I have looked in other books and apparently such a is a Nilpotent element of the ring. But I haven't found much more information about these elements. I have been trying to solve it for a long time but I have not been able to. One of the things that occurred to me is to assume that the ring is not commutative and it exists $c\neq 0 \in R$ such that $a^nc =0$, but $ca^n =b\neq 0$. Then $b^2=(ca^n)^2=c(a^nc)a^n=0$. But this doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the least $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a^k=0$. If $k$ is even, take $b=a^{\frac{k}{2}}$, otherwise take $b=a^{\frac{k+1}{2}}$. Since $k>1$ we indeed have $b\ne 0$, as you can easily check.

Comment: Or even $b = a^{k - 1}$ would work.

Comment: Yeah, that's even easier.